# Swift using variables from other files

Tags: ios, swift

I have this file named FoodHandler.swift, and I'm trying to have it appear inside of a label, and I'm getting the error **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"** This will open in a println() on the new page,

Here's my code inside of FoodHandler.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var FoodType = ""
class SwitchSegue
{

}
```

Here's my code on the new View Controller

```
        @IBOutlet var lblChose: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(FoodType) // Works
    lblChose.text = FoodType // Throws a nil exception
}
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: read error message again. google it if you can't understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error isn't about `FoodType`. You can tell because `FoodType` is not an optional value at all... but `lblChose` is. It's an "implicitly unwrapped optional", which [you can read about here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID453); it's indicated by the `!` after its declaration.

Check to be sure that the `lblChose` outlet is connected properly in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing anymore of your code, I'd assume the issue is with the label not existing.  You have declared it as an optional, but it may not be connected with a label on the storyboard.  Usually when you connect them from storyboard they will be weak:

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblChose: UILabel!
```

Answer (score -3):

You should try using (as far as I understood the println is displaying the correct value right?):

```
lblChose.text = FoodType!
```

Comment: Doesn't work, already tried it. 'Operand of postfix '!' should have have an optional type'.

Comment: Optionals are not magic—don't go throwing around exclamation points and question marks unless you know what they do! (That is, since `FoodType` is not optional, this makes no sense.)